# How to view an online markdown document in an online editor

Tags: markdown

I have an online markdown doc, say www.example.com/README.md. I want an online application that can take this URL and render the markdown in HTML. Something like this:

`www.example.com/awesomemarkdownviewer.php?edit=www.example.com/README.md`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[StackEdit](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit) can do that but only with Markdown documents published on Gist. By the way, you can use StackEdit to publish your document on different websites.

**Update:**

StackEdit can open any URL within its viewer like that:
http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/viewer.html?url=http://path/to/file.md

**Update:**

I'm the developer of StackEdit.

**Update:**

To avoid browser caching of multiple pages, use:
`https://stackedit.io/viewer#!url=http://path/to/file.md`

Comment: It'd be nice if that tool could take a random URL and render the markdown in it. The I agree, it would not be able to edit that doc, but it can let the user make a local/Gist copy of the same and let her edit it.

Comment: It seems that you are the developer of StackEdit, it would've been nice if you added a 'full disclosure' in your response to show that association :) Anyway, I'll consider this a feature-request for that tool.

Comment: The problem is that it's a pure HTML/JavaScript application. There is no server side code to download a document from an URL and show it in the page. JavaScript can not download any file from any URL from a browser. That's a security protection implemented by all the browsers. Gist has a convenient API that supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to download a file from any webpage.

Comment: I just added the feature in the application. I updated my answer. I actually created a small server side application hosted on heroku to relay the download. Let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this md file `https://raw.github.com/gurjeet/sql.js/master/README.markdown` but it barfed. Also, the md file I want to be rendered is behind an HTTP authentication, like the example shown here `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Features`, so a server-side implementation will not be able to access such documents. I understand this browser restriction on JS, so I guess I'll settle for your answer if/when the app can render any non-HTTP-auth pages.

Comment: It works just fine: http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/viewer.html?url=https://raw.github.com/gurjeet/sql.js/master/README.markdown

Comment: The website has moved to https://stackedit.io/ and it seems everything is just redicted to the main page. To get this to work now, you should use `https://stackedit.io/viewer?url=your.web.page`.

Comment: Actually both http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/viewer.html?url=your.web.page and https://stackedit.io/viewer?url=your.web.page should work but the recommended way is https://stackedit.io/viewer#!url=your.web.page so that the browser does not cache different pages. Updating my answer...

Comment: any way to do this with documents you've saved to google drive? the sharable link google drive gives you doesnt seem to work (You see the filename and then some google javascript in the editor, if you open it from an incognito window)

Comment: I get "Your browser is not supported, sorry!" on Chromium.  Downvoting.

Comment: @benweet can you update the answer again to make it work with StackEdit 5? Thanks.

Comment: Nice, but newline in markdown source are rendered as newlines in the rendered HTML document, and that't not the standard Markdown approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in viewing a markdown formatted document from a given URL have a look at [Markdown Styler](https://matteobrusa.github.io/md-styler/).

It supports appending the URL to your markdown document as GET parameter:

`https://matteobrusa.github.io/md-styler/?url=https://my.site/my/url.md`

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Markdown Styler, which I have created to show formatted markdown documents from Dropbox shared links.

Comment: Works, but it doesn't support inline LaTeX equations.