# How to open a local document with StackEdit viewer?

Tags: stackedit

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461310/how-to-view-an-online-markdown-document-in-an-online-editor) I learned this syntax:

```
https://stackedit.io/viewer#!url=http://path/to/markdown.md
```

However I did not find how to open a local file (which is possible with the "Import from disk" dialog).

Is is possible to open a local document with a similar syntax to:

```
https://stackedit.io/viewer#!url=file:///C:/test.md
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the app](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/master/app/download.js#L3-L19) does not handle any (download) protocol but http and https.

If you just wanted to access them (not edit and save) you could run a [simple static file server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server) you could access them, just not save them. Likely useless, I know, but here for completeness.

Because the app is hosted in a browser, you wont have real access to your local File System (except through Dropbox/Google Docs, which use an API). You can see that the app also has a [local version of an MD file included](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/master/public/res/fileMgr.js#L12-L29), but again, read only.

I am sure there will be someone who might host it in [electron](http://electron.atom.io/), which would give you complete File System access with a few minimal tweaks.

I for one would love to integrate this into an internal documentation server. Along with my thousand other projects I want to work on...